# docker ps で STATUS が UP になる条件

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker-compose で Rails のコンテナを立てたいのですが
docker-compose の管理リポジトリと Rails のリポジトリを別で管理していて
人によって Gemfile のパスが固定できないので
https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/
のように
ADD ./Gemfile 
ができません

なのでとりあえず ruby 関連のミドルウェアだけインストールした状態でコンテナを起動して
bundle install や rails の起動はコンテナに入ってから行うことにしたいのですが
ベースにした ubuntu のコンテナが UP のままになってくれずコンテナに入ることができません

同時にたてた MySQL の方は何もしなくても UP になってくれるので
初めから用意されてるテンプレートイメージの方に違いがあるとしか思えないのですが
どういう条件で UP になり続けるのでしょうか

```
d59848956e1a        rails                           "/bin/bash"              5 seconds ago        Restarting (0) 1 second ago                                                     rails
565825adef28        mysql                           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 seconds ago        Up 5 seconds                    0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp                          mysql
```

試しに Dockerfile をそれぞれ

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
```

```
FROM mysql:5.6
```

とだけ書いて以下のような docker-compose で command や volume をコメントアウトして
全く同じ条件で build に各 Dockerfile の場所を指定して実行した結果
上記の docker ps のように MySQL の方だけが UP になります

```
  rails:
    build: Dockerfiles/rails/
    image: rails
    container_name: rails
#    command: rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
#    volumes:
#     - ~/git/rails/:/home/git/rails/:z
#     - ~/.aws/:/root/.aws/:z
    ports:
     - "3003:3000"
    links:
     - mysql
    networks:
      rails_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.1.2
    restart: always

  mysql:
    build: Dockerfiles/mysql/
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
     - "3307:3306"
    networks:
      rails_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.1.3
    restart: always
```

---

質問ではなぜ UP にならないか調べるために最低限の状態で動かそうとしてますが
最終的には以下のような Dockerfile で構築しようと考えています

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# 必要なパッケージのインストール（基本的に必要になってくるものだと思うので削らないこと）
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs git curl libreadline-dev

RUN git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
RUN echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
ENV PATH /root/.rbenv/shims:/root/.rbenv/bin:$PATH
RUN git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
RUN ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv install 2.5.1
RUN ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv global 2.5.1
RUN gem install bundler -v "1.16.2"

# 作業ディレクトリの作成、設定
# RUN mkdir -p /home/git
##作業ディレクトリ名をAPP_ROOTに割り当てて、以下$APP_ROOTで参照
# ENV APP_ROOT /home/git/rails
# WORKDIR $APP_ROOT

# ホスト側（ローカル）のGemfileを追加する（ローカルのGemfileは【３】で作成）
# ADD ./Gemfile $APP_ROOT/Gemfile
# ADD ./Gemfile.lock $APP_ROOT/Gemfile.lock

# Gemfileのbundle install
# RUN bundle install
# ADD . $APP_ROOT
```

---

docker logs では何も表示されませんでした

---

ベースのイメージを ruby:2.5.1 に変更してみたのですがやはり UP になりません
実行コマンドは以下

```
# docker-compose up -d --build
Building mysql
Step 1/1 : FROM mysql:5.6
 ---> 9e4a20b3bbbc
Successfully built 9e4a20b3bbbc
Successfully tagged mysql:latest
Building rails
Step 1/1 : FROM ruby:2.5.1
2.5.1: Pulling from library/ruby
bc9ab73e5b14: Already exists
193a6306c92a: Already exists
e5c3f8c317dc: Already exists
a587a86c9dcb: Already exists
72744d0a318b: Already exists
31d57ef7a684: Already exists
a2a726425592: Already exists
4f2f2375eda7: Already exists
Digest: sha256:ac6661b87cf49af14b193024f28ef223b529974bdfab58f5e8d4df37a8bdbc9d
Status: Downloaded newer image for ruby:2.5.1
 ---> 3c8181e703d2
Successfully built 3c8181e703d2
Successfully tagged rails:latest
mysql is up-to-date
Starting rails ... done

# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS                                           NAMES
95939d77b103        rails                           "irb"                    7 minutes ago       Restarting (0) 40 seconds ago                                                   rails
606f8fc24dcf        mysql                           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 days ago          Up 49 minutes                   0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp                          mysql
```

と COMMAND のところが irb に変わっています

```
# docker logs 95939d77b103
Switch to inspect mode.

Switch to inspect mode.

Switch to inspect mode.
:
```

というのが延々と表示されるようになりました

```
# docker logs 606f8fc24dcf
```

の方はいろんなログがたくさん出てきます

Answer (score 0, accepted):

context というのを指定することで
無理やり Rails ツリーの中に docker-compose のパスを埋め込んで
Gemfile をコピーしてマイグレーション実行までやったら rails コマンドで起動はしました

ただ質問で本当に知りたかったことではないので
こちらで解決できました

[docker で Rails を動かしてリアルタイムで標準出力をみたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/67226/docker-%e3%81%a7-rails-%e3%82%92%e5%8b%95%e3%81%8b%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%83%aa%e3%82%a2%e3%83%ab%e3%82%bf%e3%82%a4%e3%83%a0%e3%81%a7%e6%a8%99%e6%ba%96%e5%87%ba%e5%8a%9b%e3%82%92%e3%81%bf%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)

Answer (score 0):

まずはRails側のDockerfileをRailsが起動できる状態に持っていく必要があります。

例えばRailsを動かすためのDockerfileは次のページにサンプルが載っています。

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/

KTIさんのRailsのDockerfileは

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
```

と書いてありますから、上のリンクのサンプルと比較して不足しているパッケージがたくさんあると思います。
ここから初めてみましょう。

また、コンテナが起動しない場合や、コンテナが途中で停止した場合はコンテナIDからログを取得し、停止した原因を探ってみると良いでしょう。
質問にある例の場合、`d59848956e1a`がrailsのコンテナですから、

```sh
docker logs d59848956e1a
```

と打ち込めばなぜ起動しないかのログが書いてあるので、調査してみましょう。

### 追記（05/25 10:20）

> COMMAND のところが irb に変わっています

次のコマンドを入力して、Docker起動時に実行されるコマンドを確認してみてください。おそらくirbになっているかと思います。

```sh
docker inspect --format='{{.Config.Cmd}}' [railsのContainer ID]
```

これはdocker-compose.ymlにおいて`command`をコメントアウトしたため、もとのイメージのコマンドが実行されていると考えられます。rails起動コマンドに変えるにはコメントアウトした箇所をもとに戻してください。（以下例）

```
rails:
  command: rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
```

この状態で`docker-compose up`を実行して、railsのlogsを確認してみてください。

Comment: 最初その方法でやろうとしたんですが docker-compose の管理と Rails が別リポジトリで管理してあって人によってディレクトリ構成が違って Gemfile の ADD ができないので Dockerfile では ruby 環境の構築までを行って bundle install して rails 起動は docker run -v や docker-compose の volumes でリポジトリをマウントしてから実行したいと考えてました。

Comment: docker logs をやってみたんですが何も表示されないんですよね…　docker のインストールの仕方自体に問題があるんでしょうか…

Comment: 追加された情報に基づき追記しました。

Comment: やりたいことがうまく説明できてなくて申し訳ないです。Gemfile を別リポジトリから持ってきたくて ADD Gemfile を別のディレクトリから持ってこようとすると ADD failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: と言われてしまうので、とりあえずコンテナだけ立てて -it bash でコンテナに入ってから bundle install と rails 起動をしたいと思ったんですが、コンテナだけ起動っていうのは不可能なんでしょうか…　普通は Rails リポジトリに docker-copose をおいて ADD ./Gemfile すれば Dockerfile 内で起動までしてくれるようなんですが、社内で docker-compose だけプロジェクトをまたがって別リポジトリで集中管理されるようになってて、こういう場合どうするべきなのかが自分でもわかってなくて困ってます

Comment: 申し訳ありませんが、 `Gemfile を別リポジトリから持ってきたくて ADD Gemfile を別のディレクトリから持ってこようとすると` の部分は回答者が推察可能な範疇を超えてしまっているので、この部分は別の質問として切り出したほうが良いでしょう。それが解決しなければ今回の質問の回答にはたどり着かないと見受けられます。

Comment: 少しアドバイスすると、新規の最も単純なrailsのプロジェクトを立ち上げて、それを今回のDockerfileやdocker-composeで起動することです。これによってdocker側の設定に問題があることに調査を集中させることが出来ます。